# List elements are not showing up in a vertical line

Tags: qt, listview

On Qt 5.9.4, I have a `ListView` with `model` and `delegate` like below:

```
Rectangle {

            Column {

                Image {
                    id: img0
                    source: "images/img0.png"
                }

                ListView {

                    model: ListModel {
                        ListElement {
                            dimName: "D top"
                        }
                        ListElement {
                            dimName: "D mid"
                        }
                        ListElement {
                            dimName: "D bot"
                        }
                        ListElement {
                            dimName: "H top"
                        }
                        ListElement {
                            dimName: "H bot"
                        }
                    }

                    delegate: RowLayout {

                        StyledLabel {
                            text: dimName
                            enabled: true
                        }
                        Rectangle {

                        }
                        SpinBox {
                            editable: true
                            enabled: true
                            from: 0
                            to: 1000
                            stepSize: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The `ListView` doesn't show the `ListElement`s correctly. I mean all the elements are shown **on top of each other**, and on top of the `Image` item in the code, like this:

[image: ListView is not as I intend]

Can anybody give me a hint on how to show `ListElement`s in a **vertical** line, **one below the other**.

---

UPDATE

as suggested by @Amfasis in a comment, I explicitly determined the `height` of `ListView` item:

```
height: parent.height + 100
anchors.top: img0.bottom
```

After above modification, now the list looks better:

[image: ListView looks better]

Comment: I'm interested to see other solutions, I always end up setting an explicit height, which I find ugly

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks. I'm going to try explicit height.

Comment: just found another way, will post an answer

Comment: @Amfasis setting explicit height worked, I updated my post.

Comment: @Amfasis Can you post your solution of setting `height` for `ListView` so that I can close this question as answered?

Comment: I added a comment to my post. Basically I use the ListView in a `ColumnLayout` (instead of `Column`) and set it to a preferredHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the height of the `RowLayout`, but to set it explicitly is of course not nice. So you can use the height of the first child, or a different one if you wish (actually in your case this would be the `SpinBox` probably)

```
delegate: RowLayout {
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right:  parent.right
    //height: children[0].height
    height: spinbox.height    //actually better in your case

    StyledLabel {
        text: dimName
        enabled: true
    }
    Rectangle { }
    SpinBox {
        id: spinbox
        editable: true
        enabled: true
        from: 0
        to: 1000
        stepSize: 1
    }
}
```

Even better would be to take the max of all children, but I'm not sure how that would be done best

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this solution too.

Comment: Well, setting `height` of `RowLayout` equal to either `children[0].height` or `spinbox.height` did NOT work. But your suggested solution in your comment, i.e. explicitly setting `height` of `ListView` works!

Comment: I think it only works if the ListView has a certain height, i.e. it doesn't 'claim' height itself (in my case I set Layout.preferredHeight: 300, because my ListView is in an ColumnLayout). But agreed, it's not straightforward